# How to set up relationships between these models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, relational-database

Please forgive the title, I don't really know how to phrase this problem. Essentially I have an Elo rating system - like facemash - that has Users and Players. The `Users` vote on which `Player` is the best out of two. I would like to build a third model, `Vote`, which stores the `User` who cast the vote, and the winning and losing `Players`.

How would the `vote.rb` and the `db/migrate` files look in order to achieve this? I'm fairly new to Rails, this is my first app, and I've not used any relational stuff yet. I'm using Rails 3.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same question on an app I was working on a few months ago, and I discovered that there are many voting gems available.  I really recommend against trying to re-invent the wheel, especially when there are gems out there that will do this and more for you. :)

I've tried most of them but the one I liked the most is [thumbs_up](https://github.com/bouchard/thumbs_up).  It's got a lot of really cool features I think it should do exactly what you want it to do.

Hope this helps!